# How to trigger text in a widget using PyQt

Tags: pyqt4

This may look like a long question but it is actually really short, I've just decided to copy all the working code here.
I have a main window and a *Tip of the Day* widget.
I generated both the UI using the PyQt Designer.
I can open the *Tip of the Day* widget from the main window menu but I'm not able to make the buttons work:
I'd like to replace some text in the *Tip of the Day* widget when the previous and the next buttons are clicked.

I have the following main window called `MainWindow.py`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from MainWindowUi import Ui_MainWindow
from FormUi import Ui_Form

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # Main window user interface elements
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Main window signal/slot connections
        self.setupConnections()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def showTipDialog(self):
        '''Trig dialog Tip'''
        form = QtGui.QDialog()
        form.ui = Ui_Form()
        form.ui.setupUi(form)
        form.exec_()

    def setupConnections(self):
        '''Signal and Slot Support'''
        self.connect(self.ui.actionTip_of_the_Day, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.showTipDialog)
```

I have the following `main.py`:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from MainWindow import MainWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have the following main window UI called `MainWindowUi.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MainWindow.ui'
#
# Created: Thu May 21 20:26:31 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuHelp = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuHelp"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionTip_of_the_Day = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionTip_of_the_Day.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionTip_of_the_Day"))
        self.menuHelp.addAction(self.actionTip_of_the_Day)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help", None))
        self.actionTip_of_the_Day.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tip of the Day", None))
```

I have the following widget form UI `FormUi.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Form.ui'
#
# Created: Thu May 21 23:57:41 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(418, 249)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.pushButton_previous = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_previous.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_previous"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_previous)
        self.pushButton_next = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_next.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_next"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_next)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Form", "Here a tip I'd like to replace by pressing the buttons below.", None))
        self.pushButton_previous.setText(_translate("Form", "Previous Tip", None))
        self.pushButton_next.setText(_translate("Form", "Next Tip", None))
```

Please run `main.py` in order to open the main window and click *Help* > *Tip of the Day* to open the widget.
Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Apart from the auto-generated modules, there is no code there relating to buttons. So what do you mean by "not able to make the buttons work"?

Comment: I'm starting now with PyQt and I know how to replace or clear some text by pressing a button in the **main window** but I don't know how to do that in a **secondary widget**. Can someone show me the code to clear the `lineEdit` by pressing the `pushButton_next`? I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You have a `MainWindow` class (which you instantiate from the `main()` function) which you have written to instantiate your `Ui_MainWindow` class (thus creating the GUI) and link a button to a method which pops up the dialog.

Now just apply the same logic to the dialog. Instead of creating a `QDialog()` directly in `showTipDialog`, instead instantiate a subclass `QDialog`. Write the subclass in a similar way to what you've done for `MainWindow`. Connect the `clicked` signals from the prev/next pushbuttons to appropriate methods (which you write) that change the contents of the `QLineEdit`.